# parsleyjs not working with blur event

Tags: parsley.js

I have parsleyjs and jquery on my page and I'm trying to get parsley to work when the user clicks out of the input field. I have marked it as a required field and also set it to trigger if its blank or empty when the user clicks out of the input field. But right now its not showing any error. What am I doing wrong.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" data-validate="parsley">
<input type="text" name="firstname" data-required="true" data-trigger="blur" data-notblank="true" placeholder="First Name" />
</form>
```

Second question is there a way to trigger a custom validation method in another js file for specific input fields? If so how would I go about it in this setup.

Answer (score 2):

By default parsley only validates once there are 3 or more characters in a field.

If you want to validate on blur for empty, then you need
'data-validation-minlength' => 0 as an attribute